# Is there a single word for "At least one"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a single-word for a term that describes *at least one* ocurrency.

For example:

> I'll verify that the store has at least one access.

I thought of

> I'll verify the store's accessibility

But this possibility doesn't gives the context of one or more, just that there's access.

I want a sentence for

> I'll verify that the store has **at least one** access

With a single-word approach for **at least one**

Comment: 'The store's accessibility' means you can get _to_ the store. It doesn't mean you can get _inside_ the store.

Comment: Too easy, basically you don't need a word for 'at least one': "I'll verify that the store has an access" - that means that there must be one, possibly more - although use of the word 'access' seems a bit awkward to me, do you meant entrance?

Comment: @NigelJ It depends on context, if I was at my work in a Town Planning dept ‘accessibility’ would be a measure of the access available to people if all levels of physical ability.

Comment: Lee is correct: a[n] can mean either 'one' or 'any'.  'Any' is typical in queries of truth: "I'll verify if the store has any access."

Comment: I'll verify that the store has an  access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with "any".

> **2 : one, some, or all indiscriminately of whatever quantity**
>   a : one or more —used to indicate an undetermined number or amount
>   b : all —used to indicate a maximum or whole
>   c : a or some without reference to quantity or extent

[(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/any)

"I'll verify that the store has any access."